# how can I print "\" and avoid code split?

Tags: python

I'm trying to print multiple lines using only one print command on python,
for some reason, the \ messed up my code
for example:

```
 print("""    x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      / \
     |""")
```

Answer (score 4):

In normal strings, the backslash character acts as an *escape character*, changing the behavior of the character after it (e.g. `\n` for newline. Note that escaping the linefeed character will remove the 'newline' part of it and essentially nullify it). The usual solution to this is to use it as an escape character for *itself*: `\\` will resolve to just a literal backslash.

This isn't useful for ASCII art, of course, so Python allows us to use "raw strings": simply prepend `r` right before the quotes:

```
>>> print(r"""     x-------x
...      |       |
...      |       0
...      |      /|\
...      |      / \
...      |""")
     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      / \
     |
```

and the escape character will be ignored and won't actually escape anything.

Answer (score 2):

\ is treated as an escape character. To print a \, use "\\".

```
print("""    x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\\
     |      / \\
     |""")
```

http://python-ds.com/python-3-escape-sequences

Answer (score 0):

add escape character to escape character

```
print("""    x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\\
     |      / \\
     |""")
```

Comment: Thanks guys, very helpful:-)