# save a multiple lines in a dict in python question

Tags: python

I'm learning Python these days by myself
and I'm trying to write a code for the game Hangman.

I want to save the Hangman photos in a dict
and its multiple lines each.
I tried using \n key but it didn't work, I added the """ and check on python tutor, it accept my dict, but doesn't print any of the values can you please help?

```
hangman_photos = {"""'1': " x-------x ", '2': "    x-------x
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |", '3': "    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |
    |
    |", '4': "    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |       |
    |
    |", '5': "    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|\\
    |
    |", '6': "    x-------x
    |       |
    |       0
    |      /|\\
    |      /
    |"""}
    print(hangman_photos['1'])
```

saving in a dict mode {} can really make it easy to link a fail guess to a key in the dict - hance printing the photo needed

Comment: python dicts store data with key and value pair, so just type `hangman_photos = {'1' : '....'}`

Comment: That's not a dictionary, it's a set, you have `'1':` inside the string.

Comment: Hi Barmar,
can you please point out where I'm doing it wrong?
Its the first time i request a multiple lines dict...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all in a unique string, each key must be *before* its associated value

Reusing the picture from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61325539/2458991

you want something like that :

```
hangman_photos = {
 '1': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |
     |
     |
     |""",

 '2': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |
     |
     |""",
 '3': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |       |
     |
     |""",
 '4': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|
     |
     |""",
 '5': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |
     |""",
 '6': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      /
     |""",
 '7': r"""     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      / \
     |"""}


for i in hangman_photos:
  print(hangman_photos[i],'\n')
```

execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ python3 p.py 
     x-------x
     |       |
     |
     |
     |
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |
     |
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |       |
     |
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|
     |
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      /
     | 

     x-------x
     |       |
     |       0
     |      /|\
     |      / \
     | 

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```